# How to get data

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project, In my project I am trying to get data from backend my Api is also working fine by I am unable to display data in front end in table format. So please help me to display data in table format.
This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Profiles.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Profiles extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             products: []
        }
    }

    async getProfiles() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products');
            this.setState( { products: res.data } )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-12'>
 <table className="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Brand</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Replacement</th>
                                    <th>Discount</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.jobs.map(currentValue => 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{currentValue.name}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.position}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.location}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.salary}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )}

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Profiles.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Profiles extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             jobs: []
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {

this.getProfiles()

 }

    async getProfiles() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:7500/api/registration');
            this.setState( { jobs: res.data } )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-12'>
 <table className="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>Salary</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.jobs.map(currentValue => 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{currentValue.name}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.position}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.location}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.salary}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )}

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: You forget call getProfiles() in componentDidMount(), so nothing happens